# How to play video until it is finished without using Sleep Function in VLCLIB in VC++?

Tags: visual-c++

I am just using the below code but the problem I am facing is that video play for only 10 seconds depend on the `sleep` function.

```
libvlc_instance_t * inst;
libvlc_media_player_t *mp;
libvlc_media_t *m;
libvlc_event_manager_t* em;
inst = libvlc_new (0, NULL);
m = libvlc_media_new_location (inst, "mms://16.56.16.60:5999/Video");
mp = libvlc_media_player_new_from_media (m);
libvlc_media_player_set_media(mp,m);
libvlc_media_player_play (mp);
Sleep(10000);
```

> How Can I play video until it is finished without using sleep
>   function?

Please help !!

Comment: This code is worked Fine.But If I am trying the same code for rtp stream then I  got the error "VLC is unable to open the MRL 'rtp://100.050.1.5:7012'. Check the log for details."
m = libvlc_media_new_location (inst, "rtp://@100.050.1.5:7012/Video");

Please Guide !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Reference](https://github.com/videolan/vlc/blob/master/test/libvlc/media_player.c).

You need to call this following function after playing media.

```
static void wait_playing(libvlc_media_player_t *mp)
{
    libvlc_state_t state;
    do {
        state = libvlc_media_player_get_state (mp);
    } while(state != libvlc_Playing &&
            state != libvlc_Error &&
            state != libvlc_Ended );

    state = libvlc_media_player_get_state (mp);
    assert(state == libvlc_Playing || state == libvlc_Ended);
}
```

Updated code will be:

```
.
.
.
libvlc_media_player_set_media(mp,m);
libvlc_media_player_play (mp);
wait_playing (mi);
```

Comment: Can  you guide me how to hide the title bar of vlc media player(VLC Direct 3D OUTPUT)  in VlcLIB ?